# Is it possible to auto greed when greed and pass are the only options?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Is it possible to have Wow auto select "greed" when "greed" and "pass" are the only two options?

Answer (score 3):

It is possible however there is no in-game function that allows you to do this so you'll have to use an add on (a good example of one that can auto select greed is 'PassLoot' which you can find [here](http://wow.curse.com/downloads/wow-addons/details/pass-loot.aspx).

Hope this helps.